# Asp.Net MVC Routing and URL Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

Firstly, thank you for your answers. I have a problem about routing on Asp.Net MVC.

[image]

You can see my solution here on the photo where my controllers and views located. I would like to open "UserProfile.cshtml" from "Index.cshtml". Well, my first approach is using Ajax to post "UserProfile Action" in ProfileController.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "/Profile/UserProfile",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json"})
           .done(function(response){
               window.location = '/Profile/UserProfile'});
```

this code blocks goes to controller and hits the "UserProfile" Action but returns no error and no view. Even URL doesn't change.

```
   public ActionResult UserProfile()
    {
       return View ();
    }
```

I would highly appreciate your helpful answers and support. Thank you!

Comment: ASP.NET Core is not able to process aspx pages

Comment: your views need to be Razor (.cshtml) views and the default routing is defined in RouteConfig.cs in the App_Start folder

Comment: @peggy thank you. I've changed to cshtml. It resolved URL issue with View. but the following code block still returns nothing. It hits there but no error and no view again.                                                                        public ActionResult UserProfile()
    {
       return View ();
    }

Comment: @Johnny see the posted answer. if youre still having issues, please post an updated screenshot showing that you've changed your view to be razor and post the view code.

Comment: Why are you using `window.location = '/Profile/UserProfile'` - the whole point of using ajax is to stay in the same page. If you want to redirect, DO NOT use ajax. And your specifying `dataType: 'json'` but your method returns html so that would throw an error. `Remove the `dataType` option, change the method to return a `PartialView` and update the DOM in the callback - `.done(function(response){ #(someElement).html(response); }` to update the current page

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have Razor (.cshtml) views, not aspx for mvc to be able to serve these pages out of the box. If you have a controller action named `UserProfile` in a `ProfileController` and call `return View()`, then mvc will be default try to return the view located at `Views/Profile/UserProfile.cshtml` (it will actually also check a couple other locations such as the Views/Shared/ folder for the view). The following should work for you:

```
//located in ProfileController
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserProfile()
{
   return View();
}

//located at Views/Profile/UserProfile.cshtml
`<h4>you've found your user profile page!</h4>`
```

If you're trying to hit this view by ajax- then you'll need to attack the problem from a slightly different direction. Redirecting on the server side will not work with ajax since it is asynchronous. You can achieve this by using the `.done()` ajax callback something like the following:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "/Profile/UserProfile",
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json"
 }).done(function(response){
     window.location = '/Profile/UserProfile'
 });
```

Comment: I edited my question here in the light of your recommendations. You can see the screenshot and codes there. But the problem is still same. It hits the breakpoint in action but returns no error and view again.

Comment: @Johnny Does a breakpoint in the ajax `.done` callback get hit?  Also, if you're using ajax, its much more common to return a `JsonResult` or `PartialView` in the controller action and then act on it (show the partial view or do something with the json data) through the `response` object  in the `.done` callback.